# Как работать с submodule в Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, git, github

В общем, клонировал решение, перешел в папку локального репозитория и сделал:

git submodule add https://github.com/...

Открыл решение, и выполнил добавление какого-то проекта в главное решение, которое я клонировал на шаге 1.

Проблема в том, что изменения, которые я выполняю в submobule в главном решение, никак не трекаются и после сохранения файла, значок галочки меняется на замочек, а если попытаться сделать commit сабмодуля, то говорится, что изменений нет.

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: [Первая ссылка гугла](https://jonasr.app/2020/04/vs-git-subm/#6), предположу, что это ваш случай. Также, для студии есть GitHub [расширение](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6t4r.png), пробовали с ним играться? Может улучшит ситуацию (не факт).

Comment: очень многие гит-клиенты не работают с сабмодулями в принципе. Думаю что проще использовать внешний гит клиент с +- терпимой поддержкой сабмодулей, чем заставить родной работать нормально. Из того что знаю - тавер и соурсТри имеют поддержку сабмодулей

Comment: *"Что я делаю не так?"* - ну, как минимум, используете сабмодули

Comment: @user7860670, а как без них. если нужный проект находится в другом репозитории?